NotificationServiceExtention Xamarin iOS
I am trying to implement sending reports on receiving push notifications. Xamarin iOS. I implement it through NotificationServiceExtention. There was a problem that the service does not send reports, although the same methods work through AppDelegate. What problems can there be? Maybe I missed some important settings in info.plist.
I've been making settings in Apns and FCM. The projects are precisely connected and working, but it is the functionality that I add that is not being worked out correctly.

The problem has been solved. The problem was that NotificationServiceExtention works as a separate application and did not know the relationship to the database of the main application. It was saved by prescribing the group id and creating a method for determining the local database.
